# Wireshark filter for specific SYN packet which never received a SYN/ACK

Tags: tcp, wireshark, troubleshooting

Is there a way in wireshark to find out a single SYN that does not get answered by SYN/ACK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/60995/how-do-i-filter-tcp-connection-with-syn-and-syn-ack-without-ack-response/ you can do this by applying a filter `(tcp.flags==0x12) and not tcp.analysis.initial_rtt`. The first part finds SYN packets, and the second part find packets for which the return trip time analysis hasn't happened - which implies that Wireshark hasn't seen a corresponding ACK.
Obviously, this will also find SYN packets which were ACKed after you stopped the capture, so use a long capture.

**Edit**
This filter was too narrow, it should be:

```
tcp.flags.syn==1  and not tcp.analysis.initial_rtt
```

Comment: should it instead be  (tcp.flags==0x02) and not tcp.analysis.initial_rtt  ?

Comment: You are right, at least partially: if you want all SYN packets you need a broader filter. Edited the answer.